# Google Apps Marketplace Button returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm attempting to add the Google Apps Marketplace Button mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button) into my app, but even with the most basic setup it results in a 403 Forbidden Error. Is there a particular scope that this button requires or another step I need to take in order to get this working?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<g:additnow applicationid="{my app id}"></g:additnow>
```

Comment: is the appid you're referencing on the app store?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to add the button for an existing app that I published weeks ago but I am getting the same error. @leigero any ideas?

Comment: I found that the button only appears once the Visibility Options has been set to Public. Setting it to Unlisted or Private results in the 403 errors

Comment: Also, {my app id} needs to be the Cloud Project ID, not the Marketplace ID.

Comment: What were your configurations because even with visibility set to public I still can't get the button to show up.  Also what is a Cloud Project ID?  I think you are talking about the Project Number and that is the same as the Marketplace ID.